# Exception while evaluating Camunda DMN decision

Tags: camunda-modeler

I am trying to parse a sample decision table, but getting below exception

org.camunda.bpm.dmn.feel.impl.FeelException: FEEL/SCALA-01008 Error while evaluating expression: failed to evaluate expression ‘“Fall”’: no variable found for name ‘cellInput’

I have created dmn file using Camunda Modeler Version 4.12.0 and below is java code to parse the decision.

```
VariableMap variables = Variables
.putValue(“season”, “Spring”);

DmnEngine dmnEngine = DmnEngineConfiguration.createDefaultDmnEngineConfiguration().buildEngine();

InputStream inputStream = DishDecider.class.getResourceAsStream("/dishTest.dmn");

DmnModelInstance dmnModelInstance = Dmn.readModelFromStream(inputStream);

List decisions = dmnEngine.parseDecisions(dmnModelInstance);

DmnDecision decision = decisions.get(0);

DmnDecisionTableResult result = dmnEngine.evaluateDecisionTable(decision, variables);

String desiredDish = result.getSingleResult().getSingleEntry();
System.out.println("Dish Decision:\n\tI would recommend to serve: " + desiredDish);
```

Below is dmn file created with Camunda modeler 4.12.0

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="https://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20191111/MODEL/" xmlns:dmndi="https://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20191111/DMNDI/" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/DC/" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/dmn" id="decision" name="Dish" namespace="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/dmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="4.12.0">
    <decision id="Decision_0iitlac" name="Dish">
        <decisionTable id="DecisionTable_0gwyugh" hitPolicy="ANY">
            <input id="Input_1" label="Season" camunda:inputVariable="season">
                <inputExpression id="InputExpression_1" typeRef="string">
                    <text>season</text>
                </inputExpression>
            </input>
            <output id="Output_1" label="Dish" name="desiredDish" typeRef="string" />
            <rule id="DecisionRule_0oq0hav">
                <description>-</description>
                <inputEntry id="UnaryTests_0m9w26w">
                    <text>"Fall"</text>
                </inputEntry>
                <outputEntry id="LiteralExpression_0ii151o">
                    <text>"Spareribs"</text>
                </outputEntry>
            </rule>
            <rule id="DecisionRule_1atwuts">
                <description>-</description>
                <inputEntry id="UnaryTests_1bnxqqw">
                    <text>"Winter"</text>
                </inputEntry>
                <outputEntry id="LiteralExpression_1bzzfsr">
                    <text>"RoastBeer"</text>
                </outputEntry>
            </rule>
            <rule id="DecisionRule_0kf4y0a">
                <inputEntry id="UnaryTests_09pkbsv">
                    <text>"Spring"</text>
                </inputEntry>
                <outputEntry id="LiteralExpression_0fx9hii">
                    <text>"Dry Aged steak"</text>
                </outputEntry>
            </rule>
            <rule id="DecisionRule_020pynb">
                <description>Less Effort</description>
                <inputEntry id="UnaryTests_10ydtir">
                    <text>"Fall","Winter","Spring"</text>
                </inputEntry>
                <outputEntry id="LiteralExpression_0byu0h6">
                    <text>"Stew"</text>
                </outputEntry>
            </rule>
            <rule id="DecisionRule_19jjhib">
                <description>Hey why not</description>
                <inputEntry id="UnaryTests_03eg1qd">
                    <text>"Summer"</text>
                </inputEntry>
                <outputEntry id="LiteralExpression_0cx6p63">
                    <text>"Light Sald"</text>
                </outputEntry>
            </rule>
            <rule id="DecisionRule_1cnr8kg">
                <inputEntry id="UnaryTests_12w0ceb">
                    <text></text>
                </inputEntry>
                <outputEntry id="LiteralExpression_1g1nomo">
                    <text></text>
                </outputEntry>
            </rule>
        </decisionTable>
    </decision>
    <dmndi:DMNDI>
        <dmndi:DMNDiagram>
            <dmndi:DMNShape dmnElementRef="Decision_0iitlac">
                <dc:Bounds height="80" width="180" x="160" y="100" />
            </dmndi:DMNShape>
        </dmndi:DMNDiagram>
    </dmndi:DMNDI>
</definitions>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are writing java code to parse the DMN table yourself? The Camunda engine will parse and evaluate the table for you as part of running the process.

That being said, It does not appear that your Java code is complete as I cannot see where you are feeding in any variables. I assume that you should be providing an input variable `cellInput` to be evaluated.

dg

Comment: VariableMap variables = Variables.putValue(“season”, “Spring”);

Answer (score 0):

In the Season Column you are changing the default for the field 'Input Variable' from *cellInput* to *season*. Remove *season* from the Input variable field and make sure a value for the data season is passed in.